# MySQL select, between, AND, OR clause and query problem

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table named `item` with two attributes (`code` and `name`).
Now i want to group them in the following way:

```
group a: code between (5300 and 5310),(7100,7200),(8210,8290)
group b: code not between (5300 and 5310),(7100,7200),(8210,8290)
```

How can i do it using MySQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by 'group'?

If you want to use GROUP BY you can do that:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN
            code BETWEEN 5300 AND 5310 OR
            code BETWEEN 7100 AND 7200 OR
            code BETWEEN 8210 AND 8290
        THEN 'Group A'
        ELSE 'Group B'
    END AS grp,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY grp
```

Perhaps you just want to ORDER BY though?

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN
            code BETWEEN 5300 AND 5310 OR
            code BETWEEN 7100 AND 7200 OR
            code BETWEEN 8210 AND 8290
        THEN 'Group A'
        ELSE 'Group B'
    END AS grp,
    *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY grp
```

Also note that BETWEEN includes both endpoints which might not be what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

Group a:

```
SELECT * FROM theTable 
WHERE 
  code >= 5300 AND code <= 5310 OR 
  code >= 7100 AND code <= 7200 OR  
  code >= 8210 AND code <= 8290
```

Group b:

```
SELECT * FROM theTable 
WHERE 
  code < 5300 OR
  code > 5310 AND code < 7100 OR
  code > 7200 AND code < 8210 OR
  code > 8290
```

Everything

```
SELECT *, 'A' FROM theTable 
WHERE 
  code >= 5300 AND code <= 5310 OR 
  code >= 7100 AND code <= 7200 OR  
  code >= 8210 AND code <= 8290
UNION
SELECT *, 'B' FROM theTable 
WHERE 
  code < 5300 OR
  code > 5310 AND code < 7100 OR
  code > 7200 AND code < 8210 OR
  code > 8290
```

Comment: Just had to make it complete.